# How to add 30 minutes in time object in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I converted this string into an object:

```
import datetime
date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

when I print the time object using this:

```
print(date_time_obj.time())
```

Now I need to add 30 minutes to the time. Can someone show me how ? I tried this with no luck

```
updated_time = date_time_obj.time()+ timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Answer (score 13):

You should get rid of `time()` function since `date_time_obj` is already a valid `datetime.datetime` object (`timedelta` works with `datetime.datetime`, not `datetime.time`)

```
updated_time = date_time_obj + timedelta(minutes=30)
print(updated_time)
```

The above code would successfully give us `datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 29, 8, 45, 27, 243860)`